# Ubuntu GNOME won't resume after long suspension

Tags: nvidia, gnome, suspend, dell

I have DELL Inspiron 7559 with NVIDIA GTX960 graphic card and my Ubuntu 17.04 won't wake up after the laptop has been suspended for a long time. It shows only black screen with a cursor (sometimes only black screen). It resumes correctly when the suspension is short like 30 minutes but when it has been suspended for one night it doesn't resume correctly. Does Ubuntu hibernates computer when the suspension last longer?

Comment: Just a comment...a few months ago network wouldn't resume after a long suspend but would after a short suspend ~1 hour. Before 3 months ago it worked perfectly. Ubuntu 16.04 Unity desktop.